# Random AI Movement

Tags: unity, c#, movement, ai, random

So I'm creating a zombie game where the zombies are passive and just walk randomly all over the area when player is not near. My question is: how would I make zombies move randomly? I code in C#. Basically, there is a town filled with zombies that just wander around the area (walk randomly everywhere slowly) until the player is seen or is very near.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a [_steering behaviour_ named _wander_](https://www.google.ca/search?q=steering+behaviour+wander).

Comment: Can you provide a more clear picture of your scenario?

Comment: There is a town filled with zombies that just wander around the area (walk randomly everywhere slowly) until the player is seen or is very near.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html

Comment: Sounds like a job for steering behaviours (Wander/Seek/Flee)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to implement two AI states: Seek & Wander
The zombies will have to have an attention radius.

```
if player is within the attention radius
    seek(player)
else
    wander()
```

In each wander behaviour you will want to have a location for it to wander to.  If you have a complex area you would want to have the zombie follow a specified path.  Which I would suggest to use A* to create the paths.

```
function wander()
    if path is empty
        findPath(randomPoint)
    else
        seek(path.NextNode.position)
```

To be able to steer towards a point you want to use the dot product.  Here is what I use to steer towards a point:

```
function seek(point)
    fwd = normalize(getForwardVector())
    diff = normalize(point - this.position)
    dot = dot(fwd, diff)
    this.rotationalVelocity.y = dot * this.rotationalSpeed;
    this.velocity = fwd * this.wanderSpeed;
```

If you want to make the zombies even more dumb you could test if the `dot` product of the fwd, and diff vectors are greater than 0.  That means the zombie is facing the player.  If it less than or equal to 0 then don't seek the player.

Answer (score 1):

For random movement, define variable radius, which is the greatest distance that the zombie can go at a moment, and some sort of time variable which is how long they will stand there. Generate a vector with distance less than radius, and angle of which you want the zombie to move. Then, wait a random amount of time, and repeat. Of course, this is a very simple and "stupid" ai. Like mentioned above, A* would probably be the way to go with randomly generated obstacles to make paths.

Good luck